# How to hide element in angular if one of the two condition is true

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to hide  element in angular if one of the condition is true.

I tried with *ngIf="productID == category.Lane || productID == category.Val". It doesn't work.

```html
 <label>ProductID</label>
      <ng-select
        appearance="outline"
        
        formControlName="productId"
        [clearable]="false"
        [searchable]="false"
        [(ngModel)]="productID"
        placeholder="Select an option"
      >
        <ng-option *ngFor="let product of products | orderBy: 'name'" value="{{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }}</ng-option>
      </ng-select>
      
      <div class="row" *ngIf="productID == category.Lane || productID == category.Val">
      <div class="col">
      <label>Promotion</label>
     </div>
```

Comment: what do you want to hide here? Have you tried 'ngIf else'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With this condition:

```
*ngIf="productID == category.Lane || productID == category.Val"
```

You are saying, if first or second condition is truthy then show the element. If you want to hide it, in that case you should use the opposite condition:

```
*ngIf="!(productID == category.Lane || productID == category.Val)"
```

Answer (score 10):

Otherwise, you can use the hidden attribute instead of using *ngIf the condition

```
<div class="row" [hidden]="productID == category.Lane || productID == category.Val">
```