# Hide parent div if two inner divs are empty

Tags: css, angular

Lots of examples can be found to hide a parent div when ONE inner div is empty, but in my case I need to hide the parent div if TWO inner divs are empty:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Background: I am using Angular with ng-content select to fill the child divs with content. Sometimes none of these templates are used thus both child divs will be empty.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"><ng-content select="[child1]"></ng-content></div>
    <div class="child2"><ng-content select="[child2]"></ng-content></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you not use an `ngIf` on the parent div - something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804272/how-to-hide-element-in-angular-if-one-of-the-two-condition-is-true

Comment: Yes `*ngIf` can take care of that. And it's worth asking? do you **really** need the parent? If no, then the `*ngIf` on each child might suffix without the parent entirely

Comment: The `*ngIf` should check if either ng-content child1 or child2 exists, but I don't know if that if even possible in Angular. The parent has CSS styling attached to it and is thus needed

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi: unfortunately not because it is not empty, it contains two empty divs thus :empty will not work here

Comment: What exactly do you mean? a div does not occupy any space if its children does not occupy any space. Can you reproduce an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @tony: parent has styling attached to it (e.g. border: 10px solid red) so it will show up even if the child divs are empty. That's why I want to hide the parent div in that case

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I run out of time, but would be a shame to not share what I was trying to make. Maybe not perfect because of the time but hopefully you get the idea. PS using jQuery.

```js
$(".parent").each(function() {
  var empty1 = 0;
  var empty2 = 0;
  var who = $(this);
  $(this).find(".check").each(function() {
    var check = $(this).html();
    if(check == '<ng-content select="[child1]"></ng-content>') {
      var empty1 = 1;
    }
    if(check == '<ng-content select="[child2]"></ng-content>') {
      var empty2 = 1;
    }
    if(empty1 == 1 && empty2 == 1) {
      $(who).slideUp(100);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
height:10vh;
background:#F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="check child1"><ng-content select="[child1]"></ng-content></div>
    <div class="check child2"><ng-content select="[child2]"></ng-content></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="check child1"><ng-content select="[child1]">a</ng-content></div>
    <div class="check child2"><ng-content select="[child2]"></ng-content></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but looking for a native CSS or Angular solution only

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using Angular ViewChild:

```
<div class="column column-3" [class.hidden]="!hasContentInColumn3">
    <div class="line-1" #c3a>
        <ng-content select="[c3a]"></ng-content>
    </div>

    <div class="line-2" #c3b>
        <ng-content select="[c3b]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {
    public hasContentInColumn3 = false;

    @ViewChild('c3a', { static: true }) c3a: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('c3b', { static: true }) c3b: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit () {
        // Hide div.column-3 when line-1 and line-2 are not provided
        this.hasContentInColumn3 = (
            (this.c3a.nativeElement.childNodes.length > 0) ||
            (this.c3b.nativeElement.childNodes.length > 0)
        );
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.